# Normalizability of the Hartle-Hawking state in Liouville theory

Tags: wavefunction, string-theory, quantum-gravity, normalization, matrix-model

I'm confused about how to normalize the Hartle-Hawking state in 2D quantum gravity. We can compute the HH state for two circles of length $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ in the matrix model as $\langle W(\ell_1)W(\ell_2)\rangle$, using the notation of Ginsparg and Moore, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9304011. This is supposed to be $\Psi_{\text{HH}}(\ell_1,\ell_2)$. They do the computation and find (for pure gravity at the leading order in the genus expansion)

\begin{align*}
\Psi_{\text{HH}}(\ell_1,\ell_2)=\langle W(\ell_1)W(\ell_2)\rangle=2\sqrt{\ell_1\ell_2}\frac{e^{-2\sqrt{\mu}(\ell_1+\ell_2)}}{\ell_1+\ell_2}.
\end{align*}
This is (10.11) in their paper. The norm is then
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{d\ell_1}{\ell_1}\frac{d\ell_2}{\ell_2}\Psi_{\text{HH}}(\ell_1,\ell_2)^2.
\end{align*}
which clearly diverges logarithmically because of short circles. How should I interpret this?

Comment: I think that the "wavefunctions" here are only $1$-parameter functions $\psi(l)$ As said in page $6$, "The matrix model allows us to compute correlation functions $W(ℓ),W(ℓ) W(ℓ),W(ℓ) W(ℓ) W(ℓ)$, associated respectively with the Hartle–
Hawking wavefunction, with universe propagation, and with topology change". So $\langle W(\ell_1)W(\ell_2)\rangle$ describes a propagator, not a wave function. The formula $10.20$, for instance, describes relationship between the propagator and (euclidean) wavefunctions.

Comment: Hi Trimok, I agree that $<W(\ell_1)W(\ell_2)\rangle$ is the propagator in the "string field theory," but I think it also has an interpretation as the Hartle Hawking wavefunction on the worldsheet. This is easy to see from its definition (3.86). If we insert $W(\ell)$ into the path integral then we are creating a curve on the boundary with length $\ell$, so the path integral $\langle W(\ell_1)W(\ell_2)\rangle$ just computes the integral over all manifolds whose boundary is two circles of length $\ell_1,\ell_2$. This is $\Psi_{\text{HH}}(\ell_1,\ell_2)$ by definition.

Comment: One may wonder if the 1-parameter wave function itself is normalizable, looking at formula $10.19$ with a analogy/reference to the chapter $4.3$, and formula $4.8$, where it is said explicitely that the wave function is not normalizable.